# select text by middle mouse button

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

For a specific task I need to use middle (wheel) or right mouse button for text selection in textarea.

Is there a simple way to do that?

What comes to mind is doing it myself, handling mouse events, Pointer Lock or setCapture to achieve native feel, but I am looking for something simpler.

**Addition:**

I know how wacky this sounds. Consider case of porting software where is this behavior a key part.